# Convincing my DBA there's a sporadic issue with the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

How do I convince my DBA there's a sporadic issue with the SQL Server?

The issue: basically, major slow down... Some queries, generating execution plans, even generating scripts of existing DB objects can sometimes take forever. Even operations that should have no performance issue, like generating the create table script, can sometimes take forever.

The situation - I have a SQL Server database on which I can create tables / views / etc..

The DB is hosted on a SQL Server (MS SQL Server 2016) managed by the company's IT.

I've asked him to look into it, and I believe he's been earnest in checking logs and he says the load on the server at times I noticed massive performance issues showed nothing out of the ordinary. In fact, he said it was all under 5% (very low).

I have the exact same code and queries running in staging and development environments, it's fine there - it's even super speedy relative to the production environment.

I'm at a loss at what could be the issue to be honest. And I don't know where to start.

Comment: You'll have to add a lot details to your questions for us to help you. How are you accessing the database/server? (tools, protocols, network, firewall, ....) How far apart are you from the database server? (network) Where are the staging and development databases located in relation to you and the production database....

Comment: Have you checked for blocking and locking?  Wait stats at the time of the slow down?  Has your dba got any monitoring in place, these sorts of intermittent issues can be very difficult to track after they've occurred if there's no monitoring in place.  Personally, my first port of call would be to set up a job to collect wait stats at a regular interval, these can be very useful in highlighting pain points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with [Tara Kizer's post on Getting Help with a Slow SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/10/getting-help-slow-server/). (Disclaimer: it's on my company's blog.)

She walks you through:

1. Getting your server's wait stats since startup with sp_BlitzFirst @SinceStartup = 1
2. Getting server health data in Markdown format so you can copy/paste it into your Stack question with sp_Blitz @OutputType = 'markdown', @CheckServerInfo = 1

Comment: I would definitely recommend BO's `sp_blitz`

Comment: @Shanky see, now, that's why I use my middle initial too. BGO. ;-)